# Dragon NaturallySpeaking pretending to be in normal mode while seemingly in command mode

Tags: windows-7, dragon-naturally-speaking

This happens quite frequently: I am using Dragon NaturallySpeaking, the DragonBar says I am in normal mode, but when trying to dictate only voice commands are recognized.

When the problem appears, I don't see anything weird that happened in the recognition history window. Also, the problem seems to appear only in some specific windows such as a TakaoTalk chat window or the dictation box (that's annoying…).

Any idea what can cause the issue and how to circumvent it?

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 Professional with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In normal mode, Dragon naturally speaking do both dictation and run voice commands . It happened to me so often. However, whenever I need to work on dictations I better just stick to **Dictation Mode**. If your purpose is just dictation then please stick on **Dictation Mode**. For me, **Normal Mode** always mix up  commands with dictations. If you just need to run commands then stick on **Command Mode**. This way you can avoid this mess.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I do rely on commands pretty much all the time so the dictation mode is quite impractical for me :(

Comment: So better stick to command mode :)